# Media Pipe Code Working Fine in Python Editor but does'nt draw landmarks in react after API integration

Tags: python, react-native, flask, expo, mediapipe

**Problem:**

My code is working fine in Pycharm Editor. but I want to run it in my expo react native app Therefore I have created an API for it which does not draw landmarks inside react native. I have been trying for 2 days straight but don't know what the problem is. Please help.

**Python Code: (API)**

```
    import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
import numpy as np
from flask import Flask, Response, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

mp_draw = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
mp_pose = mp.solutions.pose

count_left = 0  # Global variable for left hand curls
count_right = 0  # Global variable for right hand curls

def calculate_angle(a, b, c):
    a = np.array(a)  # First
    b = np.array(b)  # Mid
    c = np.array(c)  # End

    radians = np.arctan2(c[1] - b[1], c[0] - b[0]) - np.arctan2(a[1] - b[1], a[0] - b[0])
    angle = np.abs(radians * 180.0 / np.pi)

    if angle > 180.0:
        angle = 360 - angle

    return angle

def process_frames(frame):
    global count_left, count_right  # Use the global count variables

    image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    image.flags.writeable = False
    res = pose.process(image)
    image.flags.writeable = True
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

    try:
        landmarks = res.pose_landmarks.landmark
        # Get coordinates for left arm
        shoulder_l = [landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_SHOULDER.value].x,
                      landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_SHOULDER.value].y]
        elbow_l = [landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_ELBOW.value].x,
                   landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_ELBOW.value].y]
        wrist_l = [landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_WRIST.value].x,
                   landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_WRIST.value].y]

        # Calculate angle for left arm
        angle_left = calculate_angle(shoulder_l, elbow_l, wrist_l)

        # Update curl counter for left arm
        if angle_left > 160:
            level_left = "down"
        if angle_left < 45 and level_left == 'down':
            level_left = "up"
            count_left += 1

        # Get coordinates for right arm
        shoulder_r = [landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_SHOULDER.value].x,
                      landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_SHOULDER.value].y]
        elbow_r = [landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_ELBOW.value].x,
                   landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_ELBOW.value].y]
        wrist_r = [landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_WRIST.value].x,
                   landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_WRIST.value].y]

        # Calculate angle for right arm
        angle_right = calculate_angle(shoulder_r, elbow_r, wrist_r)

        # Update curl counter for right arm
        if angle_right > 160:
            level_right = "down"
        if angle_right < 45 and level_right == 'down':
            level_right = "up"
            count_right += 1

    except:
        pass

    cv2.putText(image, 'LEFT COUNT', (20, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
    cv2.putText(image, str(count_left), (20, 60), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, (255, 255, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
    cv2.putText(image, 'RIGHT COUNT', (400, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
    cv2.putText(image, str(count_right), (400, 60), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, (255, 255, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)

    mp_draw.draw_landmarks(image, res.pose_landmarks, mp_pose.POSE_CONNECTIONS)

    ret, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image)
    frame_bytes = buffer.tobytes()

    return frame_bytes

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Flask API for Real-time Video Processing'

@app.route('/video_feed', methods=['POST'])
def video_feed():
    if 'frame' not in request.files:
        return jsonify({'error': 'No frame found in the request'})

    frame = request.files['frame'].read()
    frame_arr = np.frombuffer(frame, dtype=np.uint8)
    frame_img = cv2.imdecode(frame_arr, flags=cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

    frame_bytes = process_frames(frame_img)

    return Response(frame_bytes, mimetype='image/jpeg')

@app.route('/counts')
def get_counts():
    return jsonify({'count_left': count_left, 'count_right': count_right})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pose = mp_pose.Pose(min_tracking_confidence=0.5, min_detection_confidence=0.5)
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

**JavaScript Code (In react native expo)**

```
    import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Image, Text } from 'react-native';
import { Camera } from 'expo-camera';
import { EventSourcePolyfill } from 'event-source-polyfill';

const CameraScreen = () => {
    const cameraRef = useRef(null);
    const [landmarks, setLandmarks] = useState([]);
    const [counts, setCounts] = useState({ count_left: 0, count_right: 0 });

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchAndStream = async () => {
            const { status } = await Camera.requestPermissionsAsync();
            if (status !== 'granted') {
                console.log('Camera permission not granted');
                return;
            }

            const handleStreamData = (data) => {
                const { landmarks, count_left, count_right } = JSON.parse(data);
                setLandmarks(landmarks);
                setCounts({ count_left, count_right });
            };

            const startStreaming = () => {
                const source = new EventSourcePolyfill(' http://192.168.30.89:5000/video_feed');
                source.onmessage = (event) => {
                    handleStreamData(event.data);
                };
            };

            startStreaming();
        };

        fetchAndStream();
    }, []);

    const renderLandmarks = () => {
        return landmarks.map((landmark, index) => {
            const { x, y } = landmark;
            return <View key={index} style={[styles.landmark, { left: x, top: y }]} />;
        });
    };

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Camera style={styles.camera} type={Camera.Constants.Type.front} ref={cameraRef}>
                {renderLandmarks()}
            </Camera>
            <View style={styles.countContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.countText}>Left Count: {counts.count_left}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.countText}>Right Count: {counts.count_right}</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'black',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    camera: {
        flex: 1,
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
    },
    landmark: {
        position: 'absolute',
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        width: 10,
        height: 10,
        borderRadius: 5,
    },
    countContainer: {
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 20,
        left: 20,
    },
    countText: {
        color: 'white',
        fontSize: 18,
        marginBottom: 10,
    },
});

export default CameraScreen;
```